# Rigging Tank Treads (Treads Deform When Rotating on X and Y Axis)

Tags: rigging, constraints

**I'm trying to rig tank treads. I followed this great tutorial By GodRayStudio.**

**Tutorial I Followed:**  https://youtu.be/FqfIfEx5Eb8?si=RD9_6Ar59ywLq2Qy

The tutorial makes a pretty good setup, but the problem is that when I rotate the tank treads on the X or Y axis, the treads become distorted. Is there any way to fix this issue with my current rigging setup?

**Video Showing the Problem:**  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9epbc6LSvLk

[image]

**Blender File to Download:** [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: first of all, you have one curve for both treads. In the video he duplicates the tread object **and** the curve. Your curve also lies between the two tread objects, but the curve and tread object need to have the origin in the same location (and the tread mesh should have the origin in the center to make sure you have no unwanted offset from the curve). Also one of your object is scaled -1 on X and it seems you've switched the direction of the curve...?

The other thing is, nice tutorial, but I would setup the constraints differently:

1. I would only use **one** *Child Of* constraint. Set the curve as *Target* of course, then disable **only** the *Location: Y*. And do **not** use *Set Inverse*.
2. Then add **two** *Pivot* constraints. Set the curve as *Target* for both. On one constraint set the *Rotation Range* to *-Z Rotation*, on the other to *Z Rotation*.
3. Now duplicate tread object **and** curve and move them over on the X axis.
4. Add an Empty, place it between both treads, select the curves, then the Empty and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Set Parent to* > *Object* ("Keep Transform" like shown in the video is unnecessary, this has only an effect if you re-parent from one object to another).

And that's it. Now you can move and rotate your treads with the Empty.

[image: tank treads]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just one problem I'm having: When I select the curve and the treads, and Press Shift D, and move it over on the X, the duplicated curve moves over, but the duplicated tread stays where it is. Do you know how to fix that? Appreciate your help!

Comment: @RyanKingArt Oh hey Ryan, sorry I should have mentioned that (maybe I'll edit it in the answer later so everyone can find it): when you duplicate both objects with `Shift`+`D` and move them on X, let's say -2 m, then the origins of both objects are moved -2 m, but the problem is, the tread should stay on 0 relative to the curve. So either you move them both and then set the tread's X value back to 0, or you just duplicate without moving at first, then select just the curve and move it and the tread will follow automatically.

Comment: By the way, I don't know if you want your chain links to be distorted on the curve because it is a bit unrealistic. So if not, I would use a simple small quad face to be arrayed along the curve, then parent the link to it and enable _Instancing_ on _Faces_ on the quad.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I duplicated the treads and curve, but left them at there default position. I then only selected the curve, and moved it over on the X axis, and the tread moved along with it.

Comment: @RyanKingArt The only thing that's still problematic with this setup, although you now can rotate the treads in each direction, this whole setup does not make this really working tracks, it is just some kind of fake. Because turning on the Z axis for example will make the treads counterrotating like on a real tank where one drives forwards and the other backwards to rotate, but this movement will decrease the closer the Z rotation gets to 90° and will reverse beyond that (and therefore look like the tread move in the wrong direction). This is no perfect simulation of tank treads.